# How to get the pid if i only know process name in linux using proc

Tags: c, linux, filesystems, procfs

I am going to make program to get process informaition(pid, process name, virtual memory, physical memory ) using procfs.
and i want print like this

```
PID Name Virtual physical shared
1    init 1234    123       22
33   firefox 33    33       2
```

I think I can get the process information through proc/[pid]/stat 
I think I should know the pid if i want to get process information.
but the problem is how can can I get the pid only given the process name.

because process pid is changed after reboot or after terminated and restart.

so my question is 
Is there a way to get the pid if I only know process name? not using shell script

is there file in proc folder that contains all of processse running now?
suppose that I only know process name( ex) firefox), I want to get pid using proc and proc filesystem

Comment: See the program called `pgrep`

Comment: I should make program without shell script

Comment: `pgrep` isn't a shell script, nor do you need the shell to invoke it or retrieve its output. However, if you decide you do wish to reinvent that wheel, see @EricRenouf's answer below.

Comment: I could understand not using `pgrep` due to portability constraints.  But why not `ps`?  It is POSIX-required making it MORE portable than doing it yourself with `/proc/<pid>`.  Unless this is a learning exercise, you are wasting your time.....

Comment: this is assignment from school. I have to print 3 process information every seconds. and what I want to know is Is there a file in proc folder that contains informations of all process running now

Comment: what I want to know is Is there a file in proc folder that contains informations(especially process name and pid matched with process name) of all process running now. If there is file like that, I could read file and by using pid matched with process name access proc/[pid] folder. then I think I could get the informaition of process( virtual memory, physical memory)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can't use a tool like `pgrep` you could look in all the `/proc/<pid>` directories and looking at the `exe` link in each to find the one that points to the executable you want.  Or you could look at `cmdline` in each if that helps instead.